# How to disable button when pressed in Apache Wicket

Tags: java, apache, wicket

I need to disable this button when pressed. I know some hard coding methods but I want t disable dynamically using some default Apache Wicket's function.

```
form.add(new Button("Continue") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onSubmit() {
    process();
    };
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using an AjaxButton or is the requirement to use a 'normal' button?

Comment: I have to use normal button

Answer (score 0):

Since this is non-Ajax button (i.e. one that will lead to reload of the page) you can just do something like:

```
<button wicket:id="Continue" onclick="this.disabled='disabled'; return true">...</button>
```

I.e. the **onclick** JS event listener will disable the button and let it do its default behavior, i.e. submit the form.

Beware that disabled form elements are not send with submitted data! I.e. there is no way to know which button has been clicked at the server side. A workaround is to disable it in `setTimeout()`.

If you use some JS library for client-side form validation then you better do this logic in its callbacks because most probably you will want to re-enable the button if the values are not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use Wicket Ajax Button??

I think you can create a ajaxUpdate for button :

```
  Button b = new Button("Continue") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
        process();
        };
    };
        b.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onclick") {
           protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
              b.setEnabled(false);
           });
    form.add(b);
```